# Google Spreadsheet using SpreadsheetService class for android

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

While trying to access the Google Spreadsheet using SpreadsheetService class am getting `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

The below is my code:

I have included the following jar files to the file

```
gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar
google-api-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-api-client-android-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-android-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-oauth-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
gson-2.1.jar
guava-13.0.1.jar

jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
```

code is below:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("ContactsApp");// Exception occured here
service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);
try {
service.setUserCredentials("abcd@gmail.com","pwd1234");
    } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
ArrayList<ContactsModel> list = new ArrayList<ContactsModel>();
try {

String url=
 "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AsaDhyyXNaFSdDJ2VUxtVGVWN1Yza1loU1RPVVU3OFE/default/public/values";

// turn the string into a URL
URL urlString = new URL(url);

// You could substitute a cell feed here in place of
// the list feed

ListFeed feed = service.getFeed(urlString, ListFeed.class);

for (ListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
ContactsModel contact = new ContactsModel();
CustomElementCollection elements = entry.getCustomElements();
contact.EmpID = elements.getValue("Emp Id");
contact.Name = elements.getValue("Name");
contact.personalEmail = elements.getValue("personal email");
contact.workEmail = elements.getValue("work email");
contact.emergencyContact = elements.getValue("Emergency Contact");
contact.relation = elements.getValue("Relation");

list.add(contact);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ServiceException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What line is the error on? .. Also it needs an application style password, not your real ID and password.

Answer (score 0):

### Google ListFeed demo

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/google/gdata-java-client/java/sample/spreadsheet/list/ListDemo.java

The demo is basic and to the point, and I think includes all the ListFeed features. .

### URL

But looking at it, I think your url is missing the sheet ID.

```
/**********************
 * Standard google urls for spreadsheet service 
 * copied direct from google code
 *********************/
public URL getSpreadsheetsUrl() throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL(
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
}

public URL getSpreadsheetUrl(String key) throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL(
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full/"
                    + key);
}

public URL getWorksheetsUrl(String key) throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + key
            + "/private/full");
}

public URL getWorksheetUrl(String key, String worksheetId)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + key
            + "/private/full/" + worksheetId);
}

public URL getCellsUrl(String key, String worksheetId)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/" + key
            + "/" + worksheetId + "/private/full");
}

public URL getCellUrl(String key, String worksheetId, String cellId)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/" + key
            + "/" + worksheetId + "/private/full/" + cellId);
}


public URL getTableUrl(String key, String worksheetId, String rowNumber)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/" + key
            + "/records/" + rowNumber);
}
```